# Is it possible to get iCal/ICS for a calendar event using MSGraph?

Tags: office365, icalendar, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way using MSGraph API for Office 365 Calendars to get an event as iCAL/ICS ?

Comment: An ICS file is literally free text, albeit structured.  You should be able to construct your own if need be, you'd just need to get the content of the event which can be done using graph.

Comment: And a loaf of bread is just flour, water and yeast. Yet people often prefer one already baked. Why reinvent the wheel if the one you need already exists?

Comment: Because you have no other option. If you can’t fashion one yourself then you should quit now. It doesn’t look that hard. I was just trying to help mate.